# NullPointerException for statement

Tags: nullpointerexception

```
public void loadFileRecursiv(String pathDir)
{
    File fisier = new File(pathDir);
    File[] listaFisiere = fisier.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiere.length; i++)
    {
        if(listaFisiere[i].isDirectory())
        {
            loadFileRecursiv(pathDir + File.separatorChar + listaFisiere[i].getName());
        }
        else
        {
            String cuExtensie = listaFisiere[i].getName();
            String nume = cuExtensie.split(".")[0];
            String acronimBanca = nume.split("_")[0];
            String tipAct = nume.split("_")[1];
            String dataActString = nume.split("_")[2];
            //Date dataAct = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dataActString);
            //String denBanca = inlocuireAcronim(acronimBanca);

            insertData(listaFisiere[i], cuExtensie, acronimBanca, tipAct, dataActString);

            //fisiere[i].renameTo(new File("u02/ActeConstitutive/Mutate"));
        }
    }

}
```

I have a simple code that checks all files and folders recursevely when a path is given. Unfortunately, i have a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION for `for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiere.length; i++)` this line. What can be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. check whether `listaFisiere` is null or not
2. If not null, change this line as `for(int i = 0; i < listaFisiere.length(); i++)`

and

you can change your code as below

```
for(File path:listaFisiere)
{
    if(path.isDirectory())
    {
        loadFileRecursiv(pathDir + File.separatorChar + path.getName());
    }
    else
    {
        String cuExtensie = path.getName();
        String nume = cuExtensie.split(".")[0];
        String acronimBanca = nume.split("_")[0];
        String tipAct = nume.split("_")[1];
        String dataActString = nume.split("_")[2];
        //Date dataAct = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dataActString);
        //String denBanca = inlocuireAcronim(acronimBanca);

        insertData(path, cuExtensie, acronimBanca, tipAct, dataActString);

        //fisiere[i].renameTo(new File("u02/ActeConstitutive/Mutate"));
    }
}
```